# How to import cglib and objenesis for spring framework

Tags: spring, cglib

I am trying to compile spring frame locally.
In the spring-core module, it seems cglib and objenesis are not packed in the repo. I tried to manually import  cglib-3.3.0.jar and objenesis-3.2.jar but seem it needs a spring repacked version. Anyone knows where I can get these jars? Thanks

Comment: You don't. They ship a local copy. Follow the instructions on how to build the repository -> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Build-from-Source

Comment: Thanks, I am successfully to build 6.x, but failed t 5.3.x. But I think this wwill be enough for me